# Created a samll script in my Organisation Google Suite ... Does not work with Basic Google Account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I created a sheet with script for my brother in My Organisation to shared Bed and Breakfast Rental.
When he feeds the table, click in the client name cel and click on the menu, I have an error.
I found that it was a sharing issue.
The script is creating events on 2 calendars ... One on my organisation Google Calendar and one on his Basic Google account.
As soon as I put his Calendar ID, it stops working. If I put 2 calendars inside my organisation ... it works. Event if he has full rights on the google sheets.
Is there a way of doing it ?

Here is the script :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('CALENDAR UPDATE')
      .addItem('Update Calendar', 'add_events_to_calendar')
      .addToUi();
}

function add_events_to_calendar() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendar_VM = spreadsheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
var calendar_IM = spreadsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
var event_Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar_VM); // My Calendar
var event_Cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar_IM); // My Brother's Calendar
//var minutesBefore = 120
//var minutesBefore1 = 1440
//var minutesBefore2 = 7200
//var minutesBefore3 = 720

var active_range = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();

var client = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 5).getValue();
var tel = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 6).getValue();
var source = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 7).getValue();
var checkINtimeIN = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 9).getValue();
var checkINtimeOUT = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 10).getValue();
var checkOUTtimeIN = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 11).getValue();
var checkOUTtimeOUT = spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 12).getValue();

if (active_range.getRowIndex()<4){
Browser.msgBox("Merci de sélectionner le client à ajouter !");
} else { 
  
  if (client===""){
Browser.msgBox("Merci de sélectionner un client à ajouter et non une cellule vide !");
} else {

event_Cal.createEvent(client+" "+tel+" - Check IN - "+source, checkINtimeIN, checkINtimeOUT);
event_Cal.createEvent(client+" "+tel+" - Check OUT - "+source, checkOUTtimeIN, checkOUTtimeOUT);

event_Cal2.createEvent(client+" "+tel+" - Check IN - "+source, checkINtimeIN, checkINtimeOUT);
event_Cal2.createEvent(client+" "+tel+" - Check OUT - "+source, checkOUTtimeIN, checkOUTtimeOUT);

//event1.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore);
//event2.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore);
//event3.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore);
//event4.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore);
//event1.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore1);
//event2.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore1);
//event3.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore1);
//event4.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore1);
//event1.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore2);
//event2.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore2);
//event3.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore2);
//event4.addEmailReminder(minutesBefore2);

//event1.addPopupReminder(minutesBefore);
//event2.addPopupReminder(minutesBefore);
//event3.addPopupReminder(minutesBefore);
//event4.addPopupReminder(minutesBefore);

Browser.msgBox("Le client a été ajouté avec succès !");

//console.log(client)
//console.log(checkINtimeIN)
//console.log(checkINtimeOUT)
//console.log(checkOUTtimeIN)
//console.log(checkOUTtimeOUT)

}
}
}
```

Tried to share the calendars but nothing worked
I am expecting that when the script is launched ...... it pushes the events in his calendar and in mine so we can both have reminders of when clients arrive and leave.

Comment: Did he share his calendar with you?

Comment: What does the Execution log show?